How to efficiently implement auditing for high-throughput background service in .NET 8?
I have a .NET 8 background service responsible for two primary tasks:
1. Push JSON data packets to message brokers (ActiveMQ, RabbitMQ, or JMS queues):

Sends approximately 25,000 JSON data packets every 2 minutes (data size can vary from 25,000 to 20,000,000).
This process is handled asynchronously.

2. Manage multiple services using this push mechanism:

There are 21 different services running concurrently, all working in an asynchronous manner and in single database.

Each service has a 10-minute sleep interval after sending a packet.


New Requirement:
I now need to implement auditing for every data packet pushed to the broker. Specifically, I need to log each record in a SQL database with a timestamp indicating when it was sent.
Challenges:

The volume of data being processed is significant, and downtime for the SQL database is not acceptable.
The solution needs to handle high throughput efficiently without becoming a bottleneck to queue push operations.

Approaches I've considered so far:

Implementing a simple fire-and-forget service using C#'s asynchronous capabilities to log the data to SQL. However, I am unsure if this can handle the load effectively.
Using a background job processing library like Hangfire to offload the auditing to a separate worker process.

My question is: How can I ensure scalability and reliability while keeping the SQL database from becoming a bottleneck?
I haven't finalized an approach yet and am open to other ideas or improvements. Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Send the packets to a message broker and use that broker to store the records in a different database. Or configure your message broker to send a copy to another queue and then to SQL Server. In SQL Server there's no overhead to having multiple databases on the same SQL Server instance. If you want to process the audit records in-process you don't need Hangfire, only a BackgroundService with an async queue, (eg a Channel). Whatever processes the messages can batch them before inserting them to the database

thank you @PanagiotisKanavosm, In this case then, I think I will have to go with in-process and async queue. does this work well with updating existing record?

And then you might need to use SqlBulkCopy or a Table Value Parameter to handle the volume.
